# Read Dataset from Impala to SAS

Tags: sql, compiler-errors, sas, dataset, impala

In SAS i'm trying to use a proc sql to read a dataset from impala and write a subset of column in my server SAS. I'm using this code:

`proc sql; connect to impala (user="XXX" pw="XXX" dsn=impNewPROD database=db_impala); create table SAS as  select *  from connection to impala ( select a, b, c from impala_table); quit;`

The code works well but i have a problem with the column in database SAS.
For example, column a in impala table is a CHAR with 16 length while in dataset SAS i see the column is a CHAR 32.767 byte.

Why?

I aspect to have the same format.

Could you suggest a best practice to adopt in proc sql or data step to have the correct results?

Thanks!

I try with put, input and format functions in proc SQL but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do expect them to have the same display format attached? Or do expect them to have the same defined maximum LENGTH.  Those are two different things in SAS.  And if you thing the variable is defined as length of only 16 in IMPALA then there is also a disconnect somewhere.  I suspect that instead the variable is define as undefined length in IMPALA so SAS used the maximum length it supports.

Comment: What version of SAS are you running. From the documentation linked below support for CHAR or VARCHAR types (the only character types in IMPALA that have a defined length) is not supported until SAS 9.4m3.  Make sure you are using a version released in the last 9 years.

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n0usrxwbz3hw7qn1nqb2zwp1ho84.htm#n04ld6zmg63kxun19fnh82wjy3jj), this is an expected result of the SAS/ACCESS engine when querying an Impala database.

> STRING: Depending on the length of Impala string data, the SAS character format ($32767.) might be unnecessarily large for short STRING columns. Alternatively, the SAS character format ($32767.) might truncate Impala STRING columns that contain more than 32,767 characters.

Once you do your query, you can shrink the column. e.g.

```
proc sql; 
    connect to impala (user="XXX" pw="XXX" dsn=impNewPROD database=db_impala); 
        create table SAS as  
        select *  
        from connection to impala 
            (select a, b, c from impala_table)
    ; 
quit;

data sas;
    length a $16.;
    set sas;
run;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [squeeze macro](https://support.sas.com/kb/24/804.html) to shrink all of the character columns to their minimum required length:

```
%squeeze(sas, sas);
```

Comment: Note the wording on that documentation page is poor. It is actually the LENGTH of the variable, not the display format attached to it that is important.